# nutch on Hadoop on google cloud- gloud dataproc

Tags: hadoop, nutch, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I get below error when i try to run nutch on hadoop on google cloud (dataproc). any idea why i would be facing the issue

```
user@cluster-1-m:~/apache-nutch-1.7/build$ hadoop jar /home/user/apache-nutch-1.7/runtime/deploy/apache-nutch-1.7.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl /tmp/testnutch/input/urls.txt -solr http://SOLRIP:8080/solr/ -depth 5 -topN2
```

> 16/09/11 17:57:38 INFO crawl.Crawl: crawl started in:
>   crawl-20160911175737 16/09/11 17:57:38 INFO crawl.Crawl: rootUrlDir =
>   -topN2 16/09/11 17:57:38 INFO crawl.Crawl: threads = 10 16/09/11 17:57:38 INFO crawl.Crawl: depth = 5 16/09/11 17:57:38 INFO
>   crawl.Crawl: solrUrl=http://SOLRIP:8080/solr/ 16/09/11 17:57:38 WARN
>   conf.Configuration: Could not make crawl/20160911175738 in local
>   directories from mapredu ce.cluster.local.dir 16/09/11 17:57:38 WARN
>   conf.Configuration:
>   mapreduce.cluster.local.dir[0]=/hadoop/mapred/local Exception in
>   thread "main" java.io.IOException: No valid local directories in
>   property: mapreduce.cluster.local. dir
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLocalPath(Configuration.java:2302)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getLocalPath(JobConf.java:569)
>           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:123)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception because you're running the job as user `user` who isn't in the `hadoop` group by default, and so the driver is unable to access the local dir. Try the following:

```
sudo sudo -u mapred hadoop jar \
    /home/user/apache-nutch-1.7/runtime/deploy/apache-nutch-1.7.job \
    org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl /tmp/testnutch/input/urls.txt \
    -solr http://SOLRIP:8080/solr/ -depth 5 -topN2
```

Alternatively, if you want to submit via the Dataproc jobs API without SSH'ing into the cluster, Dataproc will run with sufficient permissions as well:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster cluster-1 \
    --jar apache-nutch-1.7.jar \
    org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl /tmp/testnutch/input/urls.txt \
    -solr http://SOLRIP:8080/solr/ -depth 5 -topN2
```